# Multi-threaded alternative to tinyproxy?

Tags: nginx, squid, haproxy, http-proxy, tinyproxy

Are there any free, light-weight, single-process (e.g. multi-threaded, [asyncore](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html)) HTTP forward proxy software?

[Tinyproxy](https://www.banu.com/tinyproxy/) works great, but it uses multiple processes like (Apache's) prefork. HAProxy and nginx are reverse proxies don't seem to have forward proxy functions. Squid is huge...

Comment: Any chance you'd post your "hacky config" for using nginx as a forward proxy? I'm trying to do something similar.

Comment: Inside the server block: `location / { proxy_pass $scheme://$http_host$request_uri; }`

Comment: Won't quite work for my present situation, but that's a clever trick I will try to remember. Thanks.

Comment: The question is really: what is bad about multiple processes? Functionality-wise, it should not make a big difference, and tinyproxy's memory footprint is really small.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) is a "non-caching web proxy with advanced filtering capabilities". But... What is wrong with using multiple processes? Due to the nature of how processes/threads are created on Linux (and some unixes) there's not much difference between a software that uses many children processes or threads...

If your concern is resource usage, you can tune `tinyproxy` much like apache (Min servers, min spare servers, max servers, etc...).

Comment: I ended up using nginx as a forward proxy with some hacky config. Thanks for you answer though :)